# Why dont these two methods work the same?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I want to create a method that would show elements of an array , the first method `elementsOfArray` when is called instead of displaying elements of the given array inside `()` it displays elements of the array inside the method (in this case there are no elements so it just displays , , , ,) but method named `elementsOfArray1` is working fine I don't get whats there so much difference between these two methods , why do I have to declare another array inside the method instead of just using the one that I declared as parameter inside `()`?

```
class Program
{
    static void elementsOfArray(string[] array)
    {
        array = new string[array.Length];
        int i;
        for ( i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
            Console.Write(array[i] + ",");
        Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
    }
    static void elementsOfArray1(string[] array)
    {
       string[] array1 = new string[array.Length];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
            Console.Write(array[i] + ",");
        Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] names = { "Robert", "Allen", "Brandon", "Jack", "Erwin" };
        elementsOfArray(names);
        elementsOfArray1(names);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give us the full output of both? That might help us actually spot the difference.

Comment: "why do I have to declare another array inside the method instead of just using the one that I declared as parameter inside ()?" You don't. That's actually the thing that messes everything up. The line `string[] array1 = new string[array.Length];` in the 2nd method doesn't do anything. The line `array = new string[array.Length];` in the 1st method messes everything up. So just remove these lines.

Comment: @Dennis_E  I see it isn't even necessary  I can go straight with the loop thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear!
In the first method `elementsOfArray` you are initializing your array again:

```
array = new string[array.Length];
```

and you make it empty. but in the second one `elementsOfArray1`:

```
string[] array1 = new string[array.Length];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
    Console.Write(array[i] + ",");
```

you are looping through `array`, not `array1` and you didn't change `array`

Comment: Ahh I see thank you for the explanation now I understand

Comment: Correct this is what is happening in your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are re assigning `array` with `new string[array.Length];` i.e. `total number of array items but not copying array items values` in first method

```
        static void elementsOfArray(string[] array)
        {
           array = new string[array.Length];
           int i;
           for (i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
                Console.Write(array[i] + ",");
                //Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
        }
```

In second method `string[] array1 = new string[array.Length];` . `array1` also holds array of 5 empty strings

```
    static void elementsOfArray1(string[] array)
    {
        string[] array1 = new string[array.Length];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
            Console.Write(array[i] + ",");
       // Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
    }
```

If you want both methods to behave like same . Just replace

```
for (i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        Console.Write(array[i] + ",");
```

with

```
for (i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        Console.Write(array1[i] + ",");
```

You will be getting same results i.e. `,,,,,`